# Get result of radio button that is used for searching within table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a group of radio buttons which have three types for radio button options.
1. simple radio buttons
2. Radio button for input box 
3. Radio button for search box. Search box is used for search text within a table.

I am using jQuery to get result of selected radio button which is attached here:

```js
 console.clear();

    function inputSelected() {
      $("#result").html(function() {
        var str = '';
        $(":checked").each(function() {
          str += $(this).val() + " ";
        });
        return str;
      });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("input[type=radio]").click(inputSelected);

      $("td.other").click(function() {
        $(this).find('input[type=text]').focus();
      });

      $("td.other input[type=text]").keyup(function(e) {
        var value = $(this).val().trim();

        if (value.length <= 0) {
          value = 'Other';
        }

        $(this).parent().siblings("input[type=radio]").val(value);
        $(this).parent().siblings("label").html(value);

        inputSelected();

      })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<table width="200" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><input name="a" type="radio" value="a" />A</td>
    <td><input name="b" type="radio" value="b" />B</td>
    <td><input name="c" type="radio" value="c" />C</td>
    <td><input name="d" type="radio" value="d" />D</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="other"><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" id="a28" value="Other" /><label for="a28">Other</label>
       <div class="text">
                <input type="text" id="other1" value="Other">
             </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input name="c" type="radio" value="search" />Search<input id='adjectiveSearch' type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search..."></td>
    <td><input name="d" type="radio" value="d" />D</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="result">
 </div>
```

I tried to make script for search option like i used for other but it is not working.

My question is-- for such situation, what changes have I got to make to get result of search box?

Note: Search box is using for finding and whatever we find in Table it should be display as result like other radio button do.

Kindly advise me if it is possible to make something like that?

Comment: You want to add the value text `name="c"` in the result?

Comment: no i have a table is used for search text whatever i type on search box, i need to be appear as result like i have "other" option where i can type in  text box.

Comment: you can see that text box is working well because it is 'type="text"' and i need changes for 'type="search"'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
console.clear();

$(document).ready(function() {
    var radioVal  = '',
        extraVal  = '';
        textInputs = $('.hasParent');

    textInputs.prop('disabled', true);
    function inputSelected() {
        $('#result').html(radioVal+' '+extraVal);
    }
    $('.radioOption').on('click', function(evt){
        radioVal = $(this).val();
        inputSelected();
    });

    $('.radioMore').on('click', function(evt) {
        extraVal = '';
        textInputs.off().attr('disabled', true);
        inputSelected();
        if($(this).is('.hasChild')){
            $(this)
                .parent('td')
                .find('.hasParent')
                .attr('disabled', false)
                .focus()
                .on('input propertychange paste', function() {
                    extraVal = $(this).val();
                    inputSelected();
                });
        }else{
            extraVal = $(this).val();
            inputSelected();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js'></script>

    <table width='200' border='0'>
        <tr>
            <td><input id='a' class='radioOption' type='radio' name='RadioGroup0' value='a' />A</td>
            <td><input id='b' class='radioOption' type='radio' name='RadioGroup0' value='b' />B</td>
            <td><input id='c' class='radioOption' type='radio' name='RadioGroup0' value='c' />C</td>
            <td><input id='d' class='radioOption' type='radio' name='RadioGroup0' value='d' />D</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='other'>
                <input type='radio' class='radioMore hasChild' name='RadioGroup1' id='a28' value='Other' />
                <label for='a28'>Other</label>
                <div class='text'>
                    <input type='text' id='other1' value='Other' class='hasParent'>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input name='RadioGroup1' class='radioMore hasChild' type='radio' value='search' />Search
                <input id='adjectiveSearch' type='search' name='search' placeholder='Search...' class='hasParent'>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name='RadioGroup1' class='radioMore' type='radio' value='d' />D
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div id='result'>
    </div>
```

Comment: its quite good but script also display value. i need to display type text only...

Comment: when i select search option it display search below and whatever I typed search box it display next to the search box. For example I select search radio button and type abc and it show me search abc... I need to display abc only instead of search abc.... Hope you get it now

Comment: I updated my example above to do what I think you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.clear();

function inputSelected(val) {
    $("#result").html(function() {
        var str = '';      
        $(":checked").each(function(e) {
             if (['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a28', 'd2'].includes(this.id)){
                 str += $(this).val() + " ";
             }
             if (['radiosearch'].includes(this.id)){
               str += $('#adjectiveSearch').val();
             }
        }); 

        return str;
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=radio]").click(inputSelected);

    $("td.other").click(function() {
        $(this).find('input[type=text]').focus();
    });

    $('#adjectiveSearch').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
        inputSelected();
    })

    $("td.other input[type=text]").keyup(function(e) {
        var value = $(this).val().trim();

        if (value.length <= 0) {
            value = 'Other';
        }

        $(this).parent().siblings("input[type=radio]").val(value);
        $(this).parent().siblings("label").html(value);

        inputSelected();

    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td><input id="a" type="radio" name="RadioGroup0" value="a" />A</td>
            <td><input id="b" type="radio" name="RadioGroup0" value="b" />B</td>
            <td><input id="c" type="radio" name="RadioGroup0" value="c" />C</td>
            <td><input id="d" type="radio" name="RadioGroup0" value="d" />D</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="other">
              <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" id="a28" value="Other" />
              <label for="a28">Other</label>
                <div class="text">
                    <input type="text" id="other1" value="Other">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
              <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" id="radiosearch" value="search" />Search
              <input type="search" name="search" id="adjectiveSearch" placeholder="Search...">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" id="d2" value="d2" />D2
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="result">
    </div>
```

Comment: yes it is working but it also take other option values. the whole radio buttons are one group and only one selected radio button should be able to display...Kindly update with it.

Comment: Check now, I've changed tags name and id

Comment: Still there is problem. Radio button is not working for search box properly. Like I select or did not select radio button, it display type text of search box. 

There is two radio buttons of same tags name (RadioGroup1)...
first is search and second is d...when you click on search radio button it display 'search' and when you click on d radio button it display 'd' and hide 'search' but when you type something in search box and click 'radio button D', it did not hide whatever you type in search box.... 

My problem is one result should be display at one time...